# Variable name as class name in python json

Tags: python, json

I have this piece of code

```
import json

class Object:
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
                          sort_keys=False, indent=4)

languages={"pl_PL":"1","en_US":"2","de_DE":"4","fr_FR":"10","cs_CZ":"6"}
def generateJSON():
    product=Object()

    for lang in languages.keys():
        product.translations = Object()
        product.translations.lang=Object()
        product.translations.lang.name = "xxx"

    print(product.toJSON())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generateJSON()
```

Which gives me an output:

> {
> "translations": {
> "lang": {
> "name": "xxx"
> }
> } }

How can I assing lang value to my Object name to get the output:

> {
> "translations": {
> "pl_PL": {
> "name": "xxx"
> },
> {
> "en_US": {
> "name": "xxx"
> }
> }etc... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the string names in `lang` each time round the loop you need to use `setattr()` and `getattr()`:

```py
import json

class Object:
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
                          sort_keys=False, indent=4)

languages={"pl_PL":"1","en_US":"2","de_DE":"4","fr_FR":"10","cs_CZ":"6"}
def generateJSON():
    product=Object()
    product.translations = Object()

    for lang in languages.keys():
        setattr(product.translations,lang,Object())
        getattr(product.translations,lang).name = "xxx"

    print(product.toJSON())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generateJSON()
```

Output as requested.